# 0x ExchangeProxy addresses point to different implementations on Ethereum and Polygon

Tags: erc-721, polygon, 0x, erc-1155

Why is it that on ethereum the 0xDef1C0ded9bec7F1a1670819833240f027b25EfF contract is a ERC1155OrdersFeature and on Polygon it is a ERC721OrdersFeature? Does is mean that there is no ERC1155 support on Polygon?